# How do i remove these icons on the taskbar in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

I would like to remove these icons shown in the picture circled in red but i quite don't know how?

[image: Picture]

Comment: Simply right click and select "Unpin from Taskbar".

Comment: How do i do that in windows 10?

Comment: Take your mouse pointer on the thumbnail, press the right click button on the mouse, and select Unpin from Taskbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove the icons show in the taskbar, right-click your taskbar > Taskbar Settings.

Go to the section "Notification Area" and click on "Select which icons appear on the taskbar":

[image]

It will open a window with all your taskbar icons and you can disable them that way.

To remove system-related (network, Windows Defender, sound, etc.) icons, the procedure is the same but the option to choose is "Turn system icons on or off"

Note that the application is still running on the background after disabling its icon.

Comment: This just hides them onto a one big tile on the taskbar.

Comment: @T.E well, if you don't want those icons, you either need to shutdown those processes or on the apps settings, change to not show up a icon on the taskbar.

Comment: Where do i change the settings of the icons?

Comment: @T.E you can either right click on the icons and exit (and remove the application from the startup so they don't come on again), on some apps there is a option to disable the icon on the taskbar (depends on which app).